# SQL Like and like

Tags: php, sql, sql-like

Is it possible to string together multiple SQL LIKE wildcards in one query - something like this?

```
LIKE '% aaaa %' AND LIKE '% bbbb %'
```

The aim is to find records that contain both wild cards but in no specific order.

Comment: "*SQL Like and like*"? Annoying question title. Isn't it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The correct SQL syntax is:

```
field LIKE '% aaaa %' AND field LIKE '% bbbb %'
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that will work, but the syntax is:

```
Field LIKE '%aaa%' AND field LIKE '%bbb%'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is useful when you are using this statement with variables.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tableName`
WHERE `colName` LIKE CONCAT('%', 'aaaa', '%') AND -- if aaaa is direct Text
      `colName` LIKE CONCAT('%', 'bbbb', '%')

SELECT * 
FROM `tableName`
WHERE `colName` LIKE CONCAT('%', aaaa, '%') AND -- if aaaa is variable
      `colName` LIKE CONCAT('%', bbbb, '%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but remember that LIKE is an operator similar to `==` or `>` in other languages. You still have to specify the other side of the equation:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE myField LIKE '%aaaa%' AND myField LIKE '%bbbb%'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to string together an arbitrary number of conditions. However, it's prudent to use parenthesis to group the clauses to remove any ambiguity:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tableName
 WHERE (columnOne LIKE '%pattern%')
   AND (columnTwo LIKE '%other%')
```