# using a varchar in a select statement - i.e bob46

Tags: php, sql, select, preg-replace

im looking to get the select statement to work using a varchar, i know how to set the text using 'bob' and if the number it would be with out the ' '

basically i need it to select using it in the form of text and numeric:

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE name=bob46
```

but it wont select, my actual code is based on UK post codes which consist of 8 characters max, with a space everytime.

do i need any special values? mine also comes from a form so it would come as $searchquery as the character it would pull the data from.

i have made it so all items should display but i get

> " SELECT * FROM customer WHERE postcode LIKE '&cr5 3eg&' "

appear everytime

im also using pregreplace to make sure the numbers and text are used properly, how do i make it so it registers the space between the postcode? so it sees it as s3 5rf instead of s35rf ?

thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Select customer info using `name` **and/or** `postcode` with a **one or more** searchstring(s) from **one or more** form inputs? `WHERE name LIKE '%{$searchstring}%' OR postcode LIKE '%{$searchstring}%'` is one way to go (without knowing what actually should be done with what...).

Comment: im trying to select info using the postcode only. it comes from input form. if a post code is matched i want it to display all relevant data attached to that postcode. so all the other fields in the database as long as the post code matches!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer below is for MySQL. Here's [something similar for SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072782/sql-like-and-like).

---

Here the `$searchquery` is a `string` representing UK postal code.

1) This query returns customers from matched postal area:

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE postcode = '{$searchquery}'
```

2) If you only give the beginning of a `postcode`, you may use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE postcode LIKE '{$searchquery}%'
```

3) And use this if you want to match anywhere in the `postcode`:

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE postcode LIKE '%{$searchquery}%'
```

You may parse the `$searchquery` to your liking before making the search. For example if form input is "A9 9AA" and you want to search every customer whose `postcode` begings with "A9", use for example [explode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) for getting the "A9" from the input and perform the query n:o 2.

I don't where your example `WHERE postcode LIKE '&cr5 3eg&' "` came from. [See the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html) for correct MySQL syntax: use "%" or "_", not "&".

Note. I don't know anything about UK post codes. I looked the example post code [from here](http://www.hexcentral.com/articles/sql-postcodes.htm).