# Combining like clause's - A special wildcard and a column

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Im trying to do a select statement that querys my comments column for all data that includes @"username" in a database table. For example if i wanted to find @bobby. The query would search for wildcard @ in combination with checking each element in the username column. e.g username column is

```
**USERNAME** 
bobby
foo
patrick
```

This is what I have so far ( I know its wrong but you get the idea what I am trying to achieve )

```
 "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE content LIKE '%@%' AND content LIKE "entire usename column""
```

Comment: If you are looking for a particular string `@bobby` why not do as `select * from posts where content like '%@bobby%'`

Comment: because im looking to use all elements in the username column not just one string

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly. Someone searches for `something`, and you want to check for every *content* column for `%@%` and every *username* for `%something%`.

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
WHERE content LIKE '%@%' AND username LIKE '%something%'
```

But this doesn't make much sense to be honest. Instead you probably want to do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
WHERE content LIKE '%@something%'
```

This will return every row where *content* contains `@something`.

**Based on comment**

This will go through every *username* (in table *users*) and check if it is contained in *content* (in table posts), and return the rows that have matches. This assumes that you store usernames in a separate table:

```
SELECT * FROM posts
CROSS JOIN users
WHERE content LIKE '%@' + username + '%'
```

Comment: Thats what Im trying to achieve but instead of trying to find one @something I want to find @'everything in username column'. ITs hard to explain

Comment: @NubmcNub see my update. Is that what your looking for?

Comment: @NubmcNub You're welcome. If this post answered your question, don't forget to mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

You`re using multiple sql`like` statement wrong: should be

```
column1 LIKE '% aaaa %' AND column2 LIKE '% bbbb %'
```

Same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072782/sql-like-and-like).