# Understanding why querying cities with vowels at start and end doesnt work

Tags: mysql, sql, string, where-clause, sql-like

Task:

Query the list of names from table which have vowels as both their first and last characters [duplicate].

I want to query the list of CITY names from the table STATION(id,city, longitude, latitude) which have vowels as both their first and last characters. The result cannot contain duplicates.

My query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION 
WHERE CITY LIKE '[aeiou]%' AND '%[aeiou]'
```

I found this solution:

```
Select distinct city 
from station
Where regexp_like(city, '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$','i');
```

Why isn't my query working?

Comment: Because you used like and they used regexp_like? Did you read the docs on those operators?

Comment: Providing input and output examples will be very helpful to investigate....

Comment: it seems you missed a `CITY LIKE` after the and !? At least to search with only starting with an 'a', the [] is also bad according to the answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072782/sql-like-and-like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'[aeiou]'` is a regex character class, which is not supported by operator `LIKE`. So your query won't do what you expect: it actually searches for a *litteral string* that starts with `'[aeiou]'` (and even if it was, you would need to repeat expression `city like ...` twice: `city like ... and ...` does not do what you expect either).

The solution you found uses `regexp_like()` with the following regex: `^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$`, which means:

```
^         beginning of the string
[aeiou]   one of the characters in the list
.*        a sequence of 0 to N characters
[aeiou]   one of the characters in the list
$         end of the string
```

Option `'i'` makes the search case insensitive.

This works, but requires MySQL 8.0. If you are running an earlier version, consider using a `REGEXP` condition instead:

```
CITY REGEXP '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$'
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. 
I copy pasted an old version of that query - of course it must be two times city like ... my bad.
As for [aeiou] being a regex character class - I found it on

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp

Here the brackets were used also together with LIKE - what am I missing?

Example
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE City LIKE '[bsp]%';